# Why isn't C++ catching this exception?

Tags: c++, exception

I have the following code for extracting a string out of a buffer array.
It works fine. However, the *length* variable is determined at runtime, so if it were to go out of bound, an exception would occur. Of course, the code can be easily adjusted to check if the *length* variable (in relation to the *offset* variable) falls within the boundaries. Though I'm curious why the following code does not work, as the exception seems to fly through the try-catch statement (and get caught by the debugger).

```
try
{
    string value(&buffer[offset], length);
    // ...
}
catch (exception& e)
{
    // ...
}
catch (...)
{
    // ...
}
```

Running on Windows 7 64bit, MSVCR compiled.

Comment: What's the type of `buffer`? If it's a `char[]`, there's no bounds checking, and the constructor of `std::string` can't know where the end is either.

Comment: Do you want to know whether there is something in Visual C++ to help you do this? Because standard C++ doesn't do that kind of checks.

Comment: What exactly is it that the debugger catches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing the `buffer` array beyond bounds is undefined behaviour. There is no requirement for a C++ exception to be thrown in this case. Try instantiating the string outside a try block and you'll see for sure whether an exception is thrown.

Comment: Ahh I see. I got the message "Unhandled exception at 0x512fcbd1 (msvcr100d.dll) in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x024fffff.", and got mislead by the first two words. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

I think the term "exception" is confusing you. When we talk about an exception that `catch` can catch, we don't mean "exception" in the general computer science sense. We mean specifically a C++ exception that is thrown with the `throw` operation.

You have no code that throws an exception, why would you expect to catch one? If you want to throw an exception in this case, you have to write code to do it.

Sometimes I see programmers expecting to be able to catch, for example, a division by zero. While that's an exception in the general computer science sense, it's not a C++ exception unless you have some code that creates a C++ exception when there's a division by zero and throws it.

Answer (score 1):

Your program might be causing a `fault` due to accessing a memory location that the system knows is not valid for your process, for example dereferencing a NULL pointer (always faults) or going outside the bounds of a variable in the heap (not always faults, depends on page boundaries).  These `faults` are detected by the CPU, and are a different mechanism than the exceptions that you can catch with try/catch in C++, those are part of the language and implemented by the compiler and language runtime library.

In your case since you are using MSVC you have access to an extension to the language that allows you to catch both, the __try and __except facility, you can read more about the MSVC [try-except Statement here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).